# How to make multi-keystroke function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using Python 3.5 and I want to make multi-keystroke function. I want to make a function that notices Ctrl+Q but my program didn't notice it.

Here's my code:

```
import threading, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1160, 640), 0, 0)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

pygame.display.flip()

def background():
    number = 0
    while True:
        if number < 10:
            number = number + 1
            print(number)
            sleep(1)
        else:
            print("10 seconds are over!")
            break

def foreground():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and pygame.K_q:
                    print('HELLO_WORLD')


b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
f = threading.Thread(name='foreground', target=foreground)

b.start()
f.start()
```

I also changed

```
def foreground():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and pygame.K_q:
                    print('HELLO_WORLD')
```

to

```
def foreground():
    while True:
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and pygame.K_q]:
            print('HELLO_WORLD')
```

but it didn't notice Ctrl+Q.

How can I make it?

Comment: While the question could become interesting you're not giving a lot of relevant info. ie: global keystrokes or widget's keystrokes? any specific platform or platform independent? ... But the most important, [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BPL I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible fix for your code:

```
import threading
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1160, 640), 0, 0)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()


def background():
    number = 0
    while True:
        if number < 10:
            number = number + 1
            print(number)
            sleep(1)
        else:
            print("10 seconds are over!")
            break


def foreground():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    print('HELLO_WORLD')

            pygame.display.update()


b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
b.start()
foreground()
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the bug that's causing the issue.  The problem is in the if statement that checks which key was pressed.

Comment: @MikeyB What do you mean? I've tested this thing before posting my answer and it was working, [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hjjpok2ijjx69gt/2018-06-16_16-25-14.mp4)

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't see your change to the IF statement.  I see two conditions there now.   The bug was that one line of code. I'll take down my answer.

Comment: @BPL I edited my question. Could you answer my another question?

Comment: @HoseongJeon Sure, I can give it a shot. But make sure to put the new content in a new thread, that's how StackOverflow goes. 1 question per thread

Comment: @HoseongJeon I've got a possible way to go about that problem, when you've created the new question on the new thread just let me know. Thanks

Comment: @BPL What do you mean the new thread? What do you want me to do?

Comment: @HoseongJeon Take a look this [one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19)... Usually when a question has been solved already and you've got a new one (a follow up like this one for instance) that requires new code, new comments, new validation... The right thing to do is opening a new question ("Ask the question" button)

Comment: @BPL Oh, Okay. How can I tag you when I right a new question?

Comment: @HoseongJeon No worries, use the same tags than the used on this question and I'll check it out. Or just left a comment here when it's done. Also, I'll edit your current question to make sure it matches with the validated answer

Comment: @BPL Oh.. I asked question a few minutes before you answer me, so I have to wait 90 minutes. I think I can post my question around 1 hour later..

Comment: @BPL I always thank you very much about your kindness

Comment: @HoseongJeon No problem, at the very beginning when started using Stackoverflow I used to have the same mistakes than you, ie: asking multiple questions in one thread. It takes time learn all these little Stackoverflow rules... even now I still try to improve my "how to ask good question" skills, which it's not always easy ;) . You can take a look to the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), they're quite helpful ones. Remember, good questions will tipically produce good answers.

Comment: @BPL Thank you so much. I think I have to read the link you recommended :).

Comment: @BPL I think I have to wait almost 40 minutes or so. I'll tell you when I write a new question. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: @BPL I'm sorry I'm late. I asked new question.

Comment: @HoseongJeon Ok, good, already answered, didn't know there was a limitation between asked questions when having low-rep